# How to recalculate all formulas in excel file through Javascript?

Tags: node.js, excel, excel-formula, xlsx, js-xlsx

I am trying to create a web app to open excel file on web page and I am using 'xlsx' module for this purpose.

The problem is when I modify any content through 'xlsx' module. Sheet formulas do not refresh.

For Instance, A1 = 2 ,  B1 = 2 ,C1 = sum(A1:B1) = 4. Now if I edit A1 to 3, C3 does not change to 5.

This is Object format before saving:

```
{
A1: {t: 'n', v: 3, w: '3'},
B1: {t: 'n', v: 2, w: '2'},
C1: {t: 'n', v: 4, f: 'sum(A1:B1)' ,w: 4}
}
```

A short Note: This is just a small sample code. In real project its almost impossible to manually calculate all formulas at saving stage.

And, If I had to bring 5 at C3 then I need to open that file in excel and again change A1 or B1. Is there any way to refresh all formula cells in 'xlsx'. So all formulas gets recalculated.

Comment: You can use 'exceljs' instead of 'xlxs' module.

Comment: "ExcelJS cannot process the formula to generate a result, it must be supplied" https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#formula-value

Answer (score 3):

`xlsx` does not have the functionality for recalculating formulas. You could add and use `xlsx-calc` for that.

https://github.com/fabiooshiro/xlsx-calc

Comment: As @Kielstra says just one line is needed: XLSX_CALC(wb);

Comment: This is the correct answer.